# how to compile a code with if statement in make file in fortran?

Tags: fortran

I am using fortran code to write my code. I am using a subroutine inside a loop. And the name of the subroutine is different for my various runs (I have written all the subroutines). So whenever I want to run my code for different case, I have to change name of the subroutine accordingly. I don't want to modify my code again and again. I want two write a global code. I can use all the subroutines with "If statement" in my code. In that case I will not have to modify my code every time. But in this way an extra if statement  will run at each step. Is it possible write the code in a way so that I give value of some parameter and the code compiles only with the subroutine I want with out any extra loop or statement. Or can we do it by using a if statement in make file. Thanks

Comment: Fortran can pre-process code similar to the c preprocessor (or in fact the same preprocessor in some cases).  Look into that.

Comment: There are even procedure pointers, but, really, you should show some code or we're just giving broad hints.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options.

1. This doesn't fit what your question requests directly, but having if statements for picking the right subroutine is generally of negligible cost. Using an input file that determines the subroutine to use is a good way to have one executable that can handle multiple cases.
2. There are Fortran preprocessors; using a preprocessor such as fpp is right way to have make compile your code to target a particular subroutine.
3. This is a great problem for a scripting language; if you don't know a language that's great for processing strings, this could be your chance! I wrote a program, [bake](https://github.com/alexszatmary/bake), because I had a problem similar to you. Making a program to manage my Fortran code gave me great experience writing Python, which is what I use daily now. You're welcome to use bake, but you may want to make your own.

Answer (score 1):

GNU Fortran on Linux used to have the capability to run C preprocessor with conditional `#define`, `#ifdef` and similar

To do so you have to have the Fortran code extension set to .F or .F90 (note capital `F`).

UPDATE

It (C preproscessor) could be used on any fortran file with any extension with explicit GNU fortran option -cpp